# Right and left side properties of limsup

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real function such that limsups from the left and right are finite.
Let $g(x):=\limsup_{t\to x+}f(t)$. Is it true that $\limsup_{s\to x-}f(s)=\limsup_{s\to x-}g(s)$?

Comment: *are always finished* --- I think you mean "are finite". Probably you don't mean "always exist", since both limsups always exist and thus are "always finished" in the sense of existing (although this would be a rather strange way of saying "existing").

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry, we assume they are finite.